# WP7 mp3 file read and write concurrently

Tags: windows-phone-7, mp3, media, isolatedstorage

mp3 source : http://mysite.com/isrc=1289 (will return .mp3 file)

How to implement a media player that get mp3 from the source above, writing the stream into isolate storage, and while writing, the player is playing the song...

Answer (score 1):

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/08/16/download-and-store-media-for-playback-in-windows-phone-7-using-mediastreamsource.aspx

i hope it will help you :P